# Change CustomerID magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I need to change my customerID in my magento 2.3.4 shop.
Anyone who can guide me with that?
I want to raise the customerID to start from ID number 22500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by executing the following query on your database:

```
ALTER TABLE customer_entity AUTO_INCREMENT=22500;
```

Be sure to backup your database first.